# How to get the data in database in in ascending order based on id number

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

Currently I can view the list of my database and putting them as Sub-menus of my site, in the database they are ordered as smallest to highest (by ID)

this is the code I use to get the data on database:

```
   $database_service = get_data_of('service', 'id,slug,image,title');
```

> the 'service' in the code is the specific table I get data.

then creating a foreach loop to get the data in order, but I want it to show in a HIGHEST TO LOWEST order based on ID number.

so here's a full code on how I get the data:

```
            <ul class="classs class1 class2">
                <?php
   $database_service = get_data_of('service', 'id,slug,image,title');
                foreach ($database_service as $item) {
                ?>
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item class lcass2" href="<?php echo $this->config->item('url') . 'service/' . $item->slug; ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->config->item('img').$item->image; ?>"
                                 class="clas1 class2" style="max-width:25px;"> 
                        <?php echo $item->title; ?>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
```

how to do this?

Comment: are you doing it in Codeigniter?

Comment: yes codeigniter

Comment: Then you can follow my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$this->db->order_by('ID', 'desc');
```

in your model, before below line

`$this->db->get();`

to sort data in descending order.

You can refer below link to know more about ordering in Codeigniter.

[Order By Clause in Codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#ordering-results)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$this->db->select('id,slug,image,title')
->from('service')
->order_by('id','DESC')
->get();
```

OR you can also use this

```
$this->db->select('id,slug,image,title')
->order_by('id','DESC')
->get('service');
```

DESC meaning descending order if want to show the result in ascending order just use

```
$this->db->order_by('id','asc');
```

Check out the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=order_by#ordering-results)

Check out the [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JeIue3h0Lo&feature=youtu.be)